# Nuxt typescript not showing error in template

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

Nuxt typescript not showing error in template but showing in script
like if I don't have a user in my data and access it from template no error or the redline that shows it doesn't exist is not shown.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Vue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1561